# Temporary modifyable adapters

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, adapter, composition

I find it convenient to (and have a lot of code which) wrappers some storage object in an allocation adapter, and then this allocation adapter is used commonly to scope the guaranteed backstore in a managing object for its lifetime, which is normally the lifetime of the function call.

This seems to be using a nonstandard VisualStudio extension, however, and I'm curious as to what is a better paradigm and why..

e.g. a lot of our code still uses `CString`.  One of the features of a `CString` is the ability to lock its contents so that you can take a non-const pointer into the underlying buffer and manipulate it directly - a'la C library functions.

This makes it very easy to use a `CString` for its automatic resource management, but still interface to legacy libraries / code which needed a writable character buffer.  However, locking the buffer is not itself an RAII operation, so I made an RAII class to perform that function (like taking on a lock):

```
// replaces each occurrence of any of the given list of characters with a specified replacement character in-place
inline void ReplaceAll(CStringW & str, const wchar_t * chsOld, const wchar_t chNew)
{
    ReplaceAll(make_autobuffer(str), chsOld, chNew);
}
```

The code behind make_autobuffer is rather long-winded, but the idea boils down to returning an object that holds a lock on the underlying string's buffer, and will ask the str to release that buffer lock on its destruction, thus releasing the buffer back to control by the CString.

This is a trivial idea, and the implementation is fairly trivial as well (lots of boiler plate to make it robust wrt wide/narrow strings, and variations that take a fixed buffer size or not, and some debugging helpers, etc.).

But more generally speaking, I have often found it very useful to have a class which takes a non-const reference to an instance of something, and wrappers that instance in some sort of mutable adapter layer, and then releases the underlying entity upon termination.

The question is whether there is a better way to accomplish this than having to create a named variable to do the adaptation:

```
// replaces each occurrence of any of the given list of characters with a specified replacement character in-place
inline void ReplaceAll(CStringW & str, const wchar_t * chsOld, const wchar_t chNew)
{
    auto adapter = make_autobuffer(str);
    ReplaceAll(adapter, chsOld, chNew);
}
```

This works, and doesn't violate the standard.  I'm no longer trying to pass a non-const object by ref from a temp object - since I've forced the temp object into being less temporary by naming it.

But... that seems silly.  At the end of the day, doing the above doesn't change the meaning as far as I can tell.  And if the VisualStudio allowance was non-standard, then is there a better standard way that isn't so silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately what I chose to do to solve this was to change from using `Wrapper &` to `Wrapper` (by copy / move).

Passing a non-const wrapper by ref is a clear violation of C++ argument rules.  Having to declare it explicitly was annoying.  Passing it by value meant that I could take advantage of Cx11's move rules and maintain no copies for a `CStringAutoBuffer` (and other similar types of temporary wrapper objects), but still create one on the fly without having to explicitly name one locally.

This preserves const correctness as well.

Overall, a happy resolution to this genre of issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

> But... that seems silly. At the end of the day, doing the above doesn't change the meaning as far as I can tell.

Yes it is quite different. However, had you written

```
auto const& adapter = make_autobuffer(str);
ReplaceAll(adapter, chsOld, chNew);
```

that would be the same as

```
ReplaceAll(make_autobuffer(str), chsOld, chNew);
```

(consider what happens if the copy constructor isn't accessible for the return type of `make_autobuffer`).

> **WARNING** I just realized we know nothing about what `make_autobuffer` actually returns. Let me state my assumption: I assume you return a RAII wrapper class with implicit conversion to the parameter type expected by the `ReplaceAll` function (e.g. `char const*`¹)

---

Onto the "main question" - this seems pretty vague. I think you're talking about the MSVC non-standard extension to "lifetime extensions of temporaries when bound to non-const references".

I don't see where that comes in in the code you showed, for the simple reason that you show `make_autobuffer` being called inside the parameter list. As such, the temporary is guaranteed to exist until after that function call returned anyways, no need to bind/name things to achieve that. Not even in standard c++03.

If you wish to extend the lock to beyond the function call, then yes, name the RAII handle.

---

Similar design points in the standard library (and Boost counterparts):

- std::lock_guard needs to be named to keep the lock beyond the end of the containing full expression
- std::async returns a future that needs to be kept in a named variable if you want any semblance of actual async execution (otherwise, the destructor of the future still causes immediate blocking execution)

---

¹ LPCTSTR in your region?

Comment: sehe - thanks for taking the time to answer.  I think that my case is like a std::lock_guard.  I don't need it past the execution of the statement its in, hence convenient to not-name-it.  Yes, make_autobuffer returns an autobuffer which has an `operator const TCHAR *`.  D'oh I think I see the issue: make_autobuffer returns an unnamed instance of autobuffer, which needs to have move ctor / operator added to it (it has only non-const copy ctor).  Again, thank you.